# How do we validate, if Azure load_blob is successful using Python?

Tags: python, azure

How do we validate, if Azure load_blob is successful using Python?

How to check if the container is created, Is there a way to check if the data load to the container is completed/if the container is deleted after executing delete_container?

Comment: Please share any code that you have written to work with Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Python API references of Azure Storage, you can get a boolean value to know the completion status for the opertions like create a container, delete a container, as below.

For checking the completion status of the create/delete operation for a container.

1. [`create_container`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.create_container)

   > Returns:
   >   True if container is created, False if container already exists.
2. [`delete_container`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.delete_container)

   > Returns:
   >   True if container is deleted, False container doesn’t exist.

However, all of the operations for uploading blob not return a boolean value like the operations for container. When running the code `result = blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, blob_name, file_path)`, the result just a `None` value if succeed, or raise an exception. So per my experience, I think the code below may help checking the completion status.

```
completion_status = true
try:
    blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, blob_name, file_path)
except:
    completion_status = false
```

To check the `completion_status` boolean value to judge the completion status.

But if you would like to use REST API to do the operations for blob like [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-blob#response), you can check the completion status via the response status code whether is 201 or not.

Comment: In Python, boolean values start with uppercase letter: True and False